# How Can I Edit Order Without Create As New Order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, edit-order

I need to edit order without create same order as new order. How can i do edit order without create as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

load old order with order model

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001'); //use a real increment order id
```

do the changes that you want to change and than

save that order

Comment: How to use load old order

Comment: i edit my answer you just check